# Link application with a library including another library

Tags: c++, autotools, automake, linkage

In a project I am building a C++ library and an example application using the same library. The library should use yet another library that I have built in another project, but I fail to link all this together. I use autotools and automake in Linux.

To try to figure things out I have set up two test projects: test_lib and test_use_lib. test_use_lib contains the example application and the library libwlib. The library libwlib then uses a library within test_lib called libtl.

I have copied the libtl.a file built in test_lib and its .h files into test_use_lib and then I try to call a function libtl::hello within libtl from libwlib.

If I build test_use_lib without the example application then the library wlib.a will build. If I build test_use_lib without calling the function libtl::hello from libwlib then both libwlib and the example application will build. Building fails if I try to build the example application and from libwlib call libtl::hello. It fails with a:

```
libtool: link: g++ -g -O2 -std=c++11 -pthread -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wredundant-decls -Wcast-align -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Winvalid-pch -Wredundant-decls -Wformat=2 -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wformat-nonliteral -fvisibility=default -o example example.o  ../../wlib/src/libwlib.a -pthread
../../wlib/src/libwlib.a(wlib.o): In function wlib::hello()':
test_use_lib/wlib/src/wlib.cpp:6: undefined reference to libtl::hello()
```

In the Makefile for the example application I use LDADD to include libwlib and in the Makefile for libwlib I use LIBADD to include libtl.

I have put my two test projects on github: [test_lib](https://github.com/eragnms/test_lib) and: [test_use_lib](https://github.com/eragnms/test_use_lib) if anyone would like to take a look at them.

I would very much appreciate suggestions on what I am doing wrong.

/M

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to link `libtl` to your application. Note that `libwlib` is a static library therefore it is not possible to link anything to it. Instead it is the users of `libwlib` that are required to link `libwlib` dependencies.

Comment: Furthermore, @Mats, in order to serve such linking requirements across project boundaries, it is normal for one project's build system to expect the other project to have been *installed*.  Then there should be no need for otherwise copying headers and library files.  If that doesn't make sense in your case, then maybe the two projects ought to be one.

Comment: Thanks! I now got my test projects on github to work as I wanted.

Comment: @JohnBollinger good comment. I will reuse the”libtl”  library in a number of projects and will copy it into each project that is to use it and thus build it when I build the project that will use it. I am not sure that I will be able to install the library on the machine where my project will run, but I will give that a second thought.